# What is the difference between async([](){}) and thread([](){}).detach()?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

What is the difference between the two statements below in terms of execution?

```
async([]() { ... });
```

```
thread([]() { ... }).detach();
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
std::async  ([]() { ... });            // (1)
std::thread ([]() { ... }).detach ();  // (2)
```

---

Most often when `std::async` is being discussed the first thing noted is that it's broken, the name implies something which doesn't hold when the returned value isn't honored (assigned to a variable to be destructed at the end of the current scope).

In this case the *brokenness* of `std::async` is exactly what is going to result in a huge difference between `(1)` and `(2)`; **one will block, the other won't.**

---

**Why does `std::async` block in this context?**

The *return-value* of `std::async` is a `std::future` which has a blocking destructor that must execute before the code continues.

In an example as the below `g` won't execute until `f` has finished, simply because the unused return value of `(3)` can't be destroyed until all work is done in the relevant statement.

```
std::async (f); // (3)
std::async (g); // (4)
```

---

**What is the purpose of `std::thread (...).detach ()`?**

When detaching from a `std::thread` we are simply saying; *"I don't care about this thread handle anymore, please just execute the damn thing."*

To continue with an example similar to the previous one (about `std::async`) the difference is notably clear; both `f` and `g` will execute simultaneously.

```
std::thread (f).detach ();
std::thread (g).detach ();
```

Comment: "which has a blocking destructor, please just execute" thank you, these turns of phrase are easy to remember.

Comment: After going through all the comments I really don't find any use of std::Async, it seems just like a normal thread execution, and the main thread waiting until it async returns

Answer (score 3):

I know a good answer was given to your question but if we were to change your question a little something interesting would occur.

Imagine you kept the future returned by the `async` and didn't detach the thread but instead made a variable for it like this,

**Asynchronous code**

```
auto fut=std::async([]() { ... });
std::thread th([]() { ... });
```

Now you have the setup to what makes these 2 constructs different.

```
th.join()//you're here until the thread function returns

fut.wait_for(std::chrono::seconds(1)); //wait for 1 sec then continue.
```

A `thread` is an all or nothing thing when joining it where as an `async` can be checked and you can go do other stuff.

[`wait_for`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future/wait_for) actually returns a status so you can do things like this.

```
 int numOfDots = 0;
 //While not ready after waiting 1 sec do some stuff and then check again
 while(fut.wait_for(std::chrono::seconds(1)) !=  std::future_status::ready)
 {
    (numOfDots++)%=20; 
    //Print status to the user you're still working on it.
    std::cout << "Working on it" <<std::string(numOfDots,'.')<<"\r"<<std::flush();
 }
 std::cout << "Thanks for waiting!\nHere's your answer: " << fut.get() <<std::endl();
```

Answer (score 2):

`async` returns a `future` object, `detach` does not. All `detach` does is allow the execution to continue independently. In order to achieve a similar effect as `async`, you must use `join`. For example:

```
{
    std::async(std::launch::async, []{ f(); });
    std::async(std::launch::async, []{ g(); });  // does not run until f() completes
}
{
    thread1.join();
    thread2.join();
}
```